# What does the ELB do to determine the health of an instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-web-services

What specificaly is involved in an Elastic Load Balancer health check on an instance?

I know that it performas an HTTP(S) "ping"; does it just deem an instance "Unhealthy" if that HTTP request returns an error status `$THRESHOLD` number of times in a row?

Or does it take other factors into account, such as CPU usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only 2 factors taken into account:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html

For TCP:
Failure to connect within the configured timeout is considered unhealthy.

For HTTP:
Any answer other than "200 OK" within the timeout period is considered unhealthy.

... and of course you need to specify the `Timeout` and `UnhealthyThreshold` which will determine how many failures before the instance is flagged Unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

No just the protocol of either HTTP or TCP at this time. With HTTP you can define a "Ping Path" which can point to a file on the web server to make sure not only is the web server up and running but a expected page in rendering, but that's basically it. Thresholds, timeouts, and intervals are all customizable but again only for the HTTP and TCP protocols.