# Amazon ELB and multi domain on Nginx server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an EC2 instance running Nginx with several domains.
My config starts like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #disable_symlinks off;
    server_name _; #allow few domains

    #Adding 'www.' to url in case it doesen't
    if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
    }

  location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
  }
    index index.html index.php;
}
```

I'm not sure which ping path to use on the ELB (amazon) because if i try HTTP the instance always fails.
If i try TCP (port 80) the ping succeed.
I have to use HTTP because i want to use stickiness.

Any advice? thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Another answer on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/231332/138732) tells us, that the ELB expects nothing else than a `200 OK` status code.
This is a problem for your setup, because `rewrite` will cause `3**` status codes.

Create a new location for the ping path like this:

```
location = /elb-ping {
    return 200;
}
```

Then make sure to use www. for the ping to avoid the redirect

**If you can't change the ping domain to www. :**
You will have to move the redirect to www. to a `server` block.
Or you define a static ping target in your config.

### Easy way

```
server {
    listen 81; # What about using a different port for ELB ping?
    server_name _; # Match all if the listen port is unique,
    #server_name elb-instance-name; # Or match a specific name.

    return 200; # Not much magic.
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #disable_symlinks off;
    server_name _; #allow few domains

    #Adding 'www.' to url in case it doesen't
    if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
        }
        index index.html index.php;
    }
```

### Way too complex way

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # match hostnames NOT being www.*
    # Unfortunately matches only names with length >= 4
    server_name ~^(?P<domain>[^w]{3}[^\.].*)$;
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.$domain$1; # rewrite to www.*
    }

    location = /elb-ping {
        return 200;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.*; # match hostnames starting with www.*

    ## YOUR EXISTING CONFIG HERE (without the if block and elb-ping location)
}
```

Comment: Wow...i think this is the way to go but i dont follow all the way, can you please elaborate or give an example on the "/elb-ping"? Thx!!

Comment: When you add "/elb-ping" as a location, "www.domain.com/elb-ping" will be your ping path.  
The `=` modifier on the `location` block makes sure no other (wildcard/regex) block overrides it.  
The "www." is reuired because the URL will else be rewritten - which would then cause a `301 Moved Permanently` status code.

Comment: I see, i thing though...according to Amazon guys in order to check the ping i should issue something like this: http://<instance>/pingpath. this means that the instance name always appear as the host which will cause the ping path to be irrelevant since my ping path will be based on the domain name.

Comment: @DannyValariola: you mean you can't tell the ELB to ping to the www.* domain?  
See my update for this

Comment: i dont think you can tell the ELB to ping a domain since the default ping is http://<instance_name> then the path...since i have multiple domains on this machine i can't put the domain name, but i will give a try to your configuration!! thx!

Comment: @DannyValariola: Seems like I've been overcomplcating things (happens to me late at night). Your first aproach was pretty straight forward - except for a few lines. I will add an easier config for you to look at.